# Ejabberd mod_ecaptcha crash

Tags: ejabberd, erlang

I'm trying to install new `mod_ecaptcha` mod in `ejabberd-contrib`. But ejabberd crashed after enabling it.
My initial data:
ejabberd 23.01
erlang 25.2.3

1. I have enabled ejabberd-contrib by `ejabberdctl modules_update_specs`
2. Installed and recompiled mod_ecaptcha

   `ejabberdctl module_install mod_ecaptcha`
   `make -C .ejabberd-modules/sources/ejabberd-contrib/mod_ecaptcha/deps/ecaptcha/c_src`
   `ejabberdctl module_upgrade mod_ecaptcha`
   It's compiled without errors.
3. Installed erlang-dev `apt install erlang-dev` because without it it wasn't compiled
4. I'm using basic config

> ```
> captcha_cmd: mod_ecaptcha
> captcha_url: http://myjabber:5280/captcha
> listen:
>   -
>     port: 5280
>     module: ejabberd_http
>     request_handlers:
>       /captcha: ejabberd_captcha
> modules:
>   mod_ecaptcha: {}
> ```

In final I started my ejabberd and receive errors in error.log and ejabberd service crashes.

> 2023-06-19 19:59:11.892726+03:00 [error]
> <0.757.0>@proc_lib:crash_report/4:539 CRASH REPORT:   crasher:
> initial call: ejabberd_captcha:init/1
> pid: <0.757.0>
> registered_name: []
> exception error: undefined function ecaptcha_nif:rand_size/0
> in function  ecaptcha:pixels/2 (/var/lib/ejabberd/.ejabberd-modules/sources/ejabberd-contrib/mod_ecaptcha/deps/ecaptcha/src/ecaptcha.erl,
> line 63)
> in call from ecaptcha:img/3 (/var/lib/ejabberd/.ejabberd-modules/sources/ejabberd-contrib/mod_ecaptcha/deps/ecaptcha/src/ecaptcha.erl,
> line 107)
> in call from mod_ecaptcha:create_image/1 (/var/lib/ejabberd/.ejabberd-modules/sources/ejabberd-contrib/mod_ecaptcha/src/mod_ecaptcha.erl,
> line 78)
> in call from ejabberd_captcha:check_captcha_setup/0 (ejabberd_captcha.erl, line 573)
> in call from ejabberd_captcha:init/1 (ejabberd_captcha.erl, line 294)
> in call from gen_server:init_it/2 (gen_server.erl, line 851)
> in call from gen_server:init_it/6 (gen_server.erl, line 814)
> ancestors: [ejabberd_sup,<0.123.0>]
> message_queue_len: 0
> messages: []
> links: [<0.412.0>]
> dictionary: [{rand_seed,{#{bits => 58,jump => #Fun<rand.3.34006561>,
> next => #Fun<rand.0.34006561>,type => exsss,
> uniform => #Fun<rand.1.34006561>,
> uniform_n => #Fun<rand.2.34006561>},
> [114826259057369191|191927986778231166]}}]
> trap_exit: false
> status: running
> heap_size: 376
> stack_size: 28
> reductions: 393   neighbours:   2023-06-19 19:59:11.925067+03:00 [critical] <0.123.0>@ejabberd_app:start/2:68 Failed to start ejabberd
> application: {error,
> {shutdown,
> {failed_to_start_child,
> ejabberd_captcha,
> {undef,
> [{ecaptcha_nif,rand_size,[],[]},
> {ecaptcha,pixels,2,
> [{file,
> "/var/lib/ejabberd/.ejabberd-modules/sources/ejabberd-contrib/mod_ecaptcha/deps/ecaptcha/src/ecaptcha.erl"},
> {line,63}]},
> {ecaptcha,img,3,
> [{file,
> "/var/lib/ejabberd/.ejabberd-modules/sources/ejabberd-contrib/mod_ecaptcha/deps/ecaptcha/src/ecaptcha.erl"},
> {line,107}]},
> {mod_ecaptcha,create_image,1,
> [{file,
> "/var/lib/ejabberd/.ejabberd-modules/sources/ejabberd-contrib/mod_ecaptcha/src/mod_ecaptcha.erl"},
> {line,78}]},
> {ejabberd_captcha,
> check_captcha_setup,0,
> [{file,"ejabberd_captcha.erl"},
> {line,573}]},
> {ejabberd_captcha,init,1,
> [{file,"ejabberd_captcha.erl"},
> {line,294}]},
> {gen_server,init_it,2,
> [{file,"gen_server.erl"},
> {line,851}]},
> {gen_server,init_it,6,
> [{file,"gen_server.erl"},
> {line,814}]}]}}}}

Full logs:

Error.log https://pastebin.com/yQKefm4N

Ejabberd.log https://pastebin.com/uENVE5fC

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

> undefined function ecaptcha_nif:rand_size/0

It seems some file was not compiled, maybe ecaptcha_nif.beam or ecaptcha.so
Or they weren't installed, or they cannot be loaded.

There is a commit that improves this in ejabberd 23.04:
https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/commit/c5c7e7fc4db97022986d1595b73781571a3d59f2

First of all, check that all the source code files were compiled and installed:

```
$ find .ejabberd-modules/mod_ecaptcha/
.ejabberd-modules/mod_ecaptcha/
.ejabberd-modules/mod_ecaptcha/COMMIT.json
.ejabberd-modules/mod_ecaptcha/conf
.ejabberd-modules/mod_ecaptcha/conf/mod_ecaptcha.yml
.ejabberd-modules/mod_ecaptcha/ebin
.ejabberd-modules/mod_ecaptcha/ebin/ecaptcha_gif_lzw.beam
.ejabberd-modules/mod_ecaptcha/ebin/ecaptcha.beam
.ejabberd-modules/mod_ecaptcha/ebin/mod_ecaptcha.beam
.ejabberd-modules/mod_ecaptcha/ebin/ecaptcha_color.beam
.ejabberd-modules/mod_ecaptcha/ebin/ecaptcha_nif.beam
.ejabberd-modules/mod_ecaptcha/ebin/ecaptcha_gif.beam
.ejabberd-modules/mod_ecaptcha/ebin/ecaptcha_png.beam
.ejabberd-modules/mod_ecaptcha/mod_ecaptcha.spec
.ejabberd-modules/mod_ecaptcha/priv
.ejabberd-modules/mod_ecaptcha/priv/ecaptcha.so
```

Are all the files there? Specially ecaptcha_nif.beam and ecaptcha.so

If some file is missing, maybe you need to install the gcc compiler, or some other package to let ecaptcha.so get compiled.

If all the files are there, maybe ejabberd 23.01 is not able to load them.

The obvious solution would be to update update ejabberd to 23.04.

If you cannot update ejabberd 23.01 to 23.04 right now, another solution is that you copy ecaptcha.so to a place where ejabberd 23.01 can find it. For example, search for a file called xmpp_uri.so, and copy ecaptcha.so in the same directory.

Comment: Thank you for reply, much appreciated!

gcc compiler is installed:
` gcc --version`
`gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0`

All files in their places (according to your list).

My `xmpp_uri.so` is here:
`/usr/lib/erlang/lib/p1_xmpp-1.6.1/priv/lib/xmpp_uri.so`
Should I just copy `ecaptcha.so` to this directory? Or I must additionally edit some path somewhere?

Comment: By the way. ecaptcha.so has such rights. Is this okay?
`/.ejabberd-modules/sources/ejabberd-contrib/mod_ecaptcha/deps/ecaptcha/priv/ecaptcha.so`
`-rwxr-xr-x 1 ejabberd ejabberd`

Comment: I copied file ecaptcha.so into dir with xmpp_uri.so. Same result. Not starting... :(  Ejabberd crashed. By the way. I tried to do all this on Debian 11 few month ago and everything works fine. Now I'm on Debian 12. And service isn't starting

Comment: Are you running ejabberd inside a container, or installed from debian package, or from some processone installer?

Comment: I've installed from Debian package. Ejabberd first was installed (and than updated) with apt tool, when Debian updated from 11 to 12.

Comment: Badlop, I'm sorry to bother you. Maybe you have found bugs or my mistaked above? Still can't enable this mod.